# How does WebRTC determine when to resize a video based on adaptive bitrate?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, h.264, adaptive-bitrate, vp9

Can someone help me understand how WebRTC determines when to adjust the size of a video steam based on bitrate?

I'm looking for a slightly lower level description than what I can find with a basic Google search. Ideally, if there are any key files in the WebRTC Git repository, I'd like to look through them.

Thank you

Comment: https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/06-media-communication/#adaptive-bitrate-and-bandwidth-estimation seems to be a useful resource, it's almost too detailed.

Comment: Another useful resource is https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/video-contenthint/, which uses `MediaStreamTrack.contentHint` described in https://w3c.github.io/mst-content-hint/